# Pandas adding unwanted column of 0s in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am scanning a directory of text files and adding them to a Pandas dataframe:

```
text_path = "/home/tdun0002/stash/cloud_scripts/aws_scripts/output_files/memory_stats/text/"
filelist = os.listdir(text_path)
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in filelist:
    my_file = text_path + filename
    try:
        df = pd.read_csv(my_file, delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
        final_df = final_df.append(df)
pd.options.display.max_rows
print(f"\n***Full Data Frame: {final_df}\n***")
```

Each file in the directory holds the memory of a server:

```
bastion001-memory.txt             
permissions001-memory.txt        
haproxy001-memory.txt
```

The contents of the files look something like this:

`cat haproxy001-memory.txt
7706172`

On each pass of adding the file, it adds a new column with a 0 in it for each line:

```
***Full Data Frame:
         0
0  1843260
0  1843260
0  1843260
0  1843260
0  1843260
0  1843260
0  1843260
0  1843260
0  1843260
0  3819060
0  3819060
0  7706164
0  7904828
0  7706172
0  7648524
0  7706172
***
```

Why is it adding the new column with just a zero in it? The first line has just a `0` in it, even though none of the files it's ingesting has a line like that.

I just want what's in the second column to be in the dataframe such as: `7706172`

Comment: Is that the only column in the final dataframe?

Comment: Currently, yes.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same output by given code.

Comment: OK. Here is a paste with the entire code: https://hastebin.com/rowelevuce.py

Comment: Anyways, the first column is just index labels, which are automatically generated unless provided when creating a pandas dataframe. Those are not actual values.

Comment: OK great! Thanks for clarifying. How can I create index labels if I want to?

Comment: You can use the `index_col` parameter on `read_csv` method. You can look at the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: OK cool. Thanks! I'll check out the docs.